# C++ custom type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, custom-type

I've got a class `int32`, and it is set up in a way that it can essentially be interfaced with as an `int` (operator overloads), but there's one part I don't get.

```
int32 i32 = 100; // Works
int i = 200; // Works
i32 += 10; // Works
i32 -= 10; // Works, i32 = 100 right now
i = i32; // Doesn't work
```

What operator would I need to overload to achieve referencing i32 returning it's stored value, in this case, 100 (or how else could it be done)?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought that would suffice.. would you like me to post the entirety of `int32`'s source?

Comment: Without knowing what int32 is, noone cant tell what the problem actually is.

Comment: @JosephCaruso, the entirety of the class `i32` is not ncessary. You have to show enough code to show why you think it should work.

Comment: overload conversion operator to `int` type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add a [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) `operator int`:

```
class int32 {
public:
    operator int() const;
    ...
};
```

Note that it comes in two flavours. The above will allow

```
int32 foo;
int i = foo;
```

If you define the conversion operator as `explicit`

```
    explicit operator int() const;
```

then the above will fail by design, and require an explicit cast:

```
int32 foo;
int i = static_cast<int>(foo);
```

Comment: That perfectly described what I was trying to achieve! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
class int32{
private:
    std::int32_t value;
public:
    constexpr /*explicit*/ operator std::int32_t() const noexcept { return this->value; }
};
```

You should write conversion operator.

```
int32 a = 1;
std::int32_t b = a;//OK
```

However, it is harmful so that specify `explicit` and force cast to convert.

```
int32 a = 1;
//std::int32_t b = a;//NG
std::int32_t b = static_cast<std::int32_t>(a);
```

note: You shold not write conversion operator to int because there is no guarante `int` is 32bit.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a conversion operator on your int32 class.

```
class int32
{
    // conversion operator
    operator int() const
    { 
        int ret = // your logic
        return ret;
    }
}
```

This conversion operator will convert primitive type (int) to your defined type int32;